# Why would one use BigInteger over something like a double when dealing with integers larger than Long.MAX_Value?

Tags: integer, double, long-integer, biginteger

When dealing with integers greater than Long.MAX_VALUE why should someone use a BigInteger object over a double? A long's max value is 2^63 - 1 whereas a double's max value is ~1.7*10^308. Wouldn't it be easier and use less resources to just use a double as if it were an integer rather than creating an entire object for the number?

Comment: Look at how many digits (significant figures) a Double can hold and compare it to how many digits a BigInteger can hold.

Comment: Do you have any idea what the difference between a double and a float is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Floating point numbers (floats, doubles) gain range by sacrificing precision. They represent a value as an exponential component and a significand component, respectively:

`2^E * M`

There are only so many discrete values that a floating point number can represent, and the spacing between them gets larger as you go towards the maximum possible value. As a result, there is a *small degree of error* for most numbers, growing larger as the numbers get higher.

As an extreme example, `1000000000000000000000000000000` becomes `1000000000000000019884624838656` when stored as a single-precision floating point number. This is no good if you're trying to count things - especially when you discover that `1e+30 + 10 = 1e+30`!

This is where BigInteger comes in. It offers arbitrarily large integers without rounding errors.

As a rule, **never use floating point values for counting**. Comparisons between floats require you to provide some room for rounding errors, whilst comparisons between integers are completely precise.

Comment: You're welcome! Make sure to mark it as the accepted answer if you think it fully answers the question :D